# Is it possible to wirelessly turn the raspberry pi on/off?

Tags: wireless, power, retropie

I thought about getting a RPi 2 B and install Retropie to relive my childhood and play some oldschool games with my girlfriend(she really loves the idea). Right now I don't have a RPi, but I got 2 wireless xbox 360 controller that I don't use often.

I would like to sit down and press a button on a remote or controller and start the "console". As far as I know right now you have to plug in the micro usb cable to turn the RPi on and use a shutdown command to shut it down.

In Retropie it's easier to shut down as there's a shutdown option in the main menu. But my concern is that I use a multi power extension outlet with a on/off button. Most of the time the extention outlet is turned off, but if I want to watch something on Netflix I turn it on and turn it off if I am done watching tv.

Wouldn't that mean I would power the RPi on(booting up etc) and off all the time I just want to watch TV?

I have read that you shouldn't just power off the Pi but shut it down via command and then unplug it, or the sdcard gets corrupted.

Is there a way to stop the Pi from booting up if energy is flowing and is there a way to wirelessly turn it on/off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kept researching and found the remote Pi Board.
Although it's expensive it's exactly what i was looking for.
A review i found: [Review](http://ddurdle.blogspot.de/2013/12/remotepi-board-power-ir-switch-day-11.html) ; [Devsite](http://www.msldigital.com/)

Dylan Durdle:

> Pros:
>
> - very small
> - may need some modification to your raspberry pi case, but otherwise fits within the existing case (doesn't extend out from the board's footprint)
> - addresses the CLEAN SHUTDOWN and POWER OFF requirements fully
> - no issues with provided switch script
> - fully integrated IR receiver that can be used to allow your IR remote to control XBMC
> - everything fully assembled
>
> Cons:
>
> - expensive but it does save you cost from building your own IR receiver setup or USB IR receiver

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to stop the Pi from booting up if energy is flowing

Not, I think, that will make it more convenient than just leaving it unplugged.  For example, you could remove the SD card, in which case it
will still have power, but nothing to do.  The issue, remember, is that there is no power switch; shutting down the system (whether you type `shutdown` or use a tool or menu option that does the same thing for you) **does NOT actually turn off the power.**  It just shuts down the operating system.  After that the pi consume less power than when the OS is running, but it will still continue to consume power.  In this sense it *cannot* be turned off by any means.  It is either plugged in, or not.  There are aftermarket switches you can get (or build), however.

After the OS is shutdown the only way to reboot it (if you did not ask it to reboot) is to trigger the power briefly, either by unplugging it and plugging it in again, or by doing something which accomplishes the same physical effect, such as using the switch on a power bar.  You can also trigger a power reset by briefly shorting two special points on the board (debately you can do it by shorting some other points, lol, but that is probably not a good practice).

> and is there a way to wirelessly turn it on/off?

Reboot/shutdown can be triggered wirelessly if the system is connected to a wireless network.  You could also attach an IR receiver for this purpose, or use a physical button on the casing, etc.  You can do it however you want, as long as what you are doing results in the OS being told to shutdown or reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, a aftermarket switch i found does all this. Powermanagement + button + IR-sensor. Pretty cool. Accoirding to the review i linked to it fits into a standard case.

Answer (score 0):

I have several Raspberry Pi, and I use this [Power Distribution Unit](https://www.tindie.com/products/nigelvh/dc-power-distribution-unit/)

It works really well, and allows me to connect to it via USB and power on and off individual ports, see the power utilization, and set limits on current draw (among other things).

It comes ready to go, but I would suggest getting the associated case for it, and installing some [Anderson Power Poles](http://www.powerwerx.com/anderson-powerpoles/) on it in order to make it easy to connect devices to it.

This would allow you to connect it via USB to a laptop, which uses wireless, and then you can connect to that laptop.  That's the closest thing I can think of.